# "Not authorized on ___ to execute command" with mLab + MongoDB ^3.0

Tags: mongodb, npm, mlab

Connects without a hitch, but on `insert()` throws me this error.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://____:____@ds125565.mlab.com:25565/heroku_w268n9pj';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db = client.db('temp');
    console.log("connected!");
    const collection = db.collection('temp');
    collection.insert([{
        something: please
    }
});
```

I saw some other answers regarding mLab accounts and credentials, but I just created a new admin account for this. Frustrating because it was working previously with v2.3.

Comment: same error with mongo shell or with pymongo

Comment: Hey, don't know if you've solved this yet, but that connection string looks like a Sandbox plan. You only have access to one database on Sandbox plans. The database name in your connection string is `heroku_w268n9pj`. so try `db = client.db('heroku_w268n9pj')`. Otherwise, you're trying to run commands on the `temp` database - which you do not have access to.

Comment: The reason this worked with 2.3 but not 3.0 is in 2.3 the `db` object was created automatically from the connection string. Whereas now you need to specify the db name yourself. Make sure it's the same one as in the connection string.

Comment: Both suggestions work.

Comment: @tfogo Would be nice to post this as answer :-)

Comment: @tfogo, please, could you post a full reply with an example of what you said ?

Comment: @tfogo, please, write the answer, I wanna give +10 reps for you, u saved my hours =)

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to connect to an mlab database, you have to correctly specify the client. It's located at the end of your connection string, just after the final forward slash.

```
mlab_url = "mongodb://db_user_name:db_password@ds139725.mlab.com:39725/heroku_sd1fp182?retryWrites=false"
client = MongoClient(url)


db = client["heroku_sd1fp182"]
collection = db["coinHack"]
```

You may also get the error:

This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string.

Just add "?retryWrites=false" to your connection string, as shown above.